# How to combine several maps into a single map in flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I combine 2 or more maps in dart into 1 map? for example, I have something like:

```
 var firstMap = {"1":"2"};
 var secondMap = {"1":"2"};
 var thirdMap = {"1":"2"};
```

I want: maps within a map

```
var finalMap = { {"1":"2"}, {"1":"2"}, {"1":"2"} };
```

Comment: Your `finalMap` isn't a `Map` since it has no keys.  What exactly do you want?  If you just a list of `Map`s, you can do `var list = [firstMap, secondMap, thirdMap]`.

Answer (score 0):

As we know that map is   "key and Value " combination what i think try to use list not map.